# Find MAC-Address using ADF mobile

Tags: oracle-adf, mac-address

I am trying to retrieve the MAC address of the device using ADF. Is this possible?

This is some information that I was able to get, but I couldnt understand how to use it.(I dont know whether this link is of much use as it is the documentation to Oracle® Identity Management)

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E27559_01/admin.1112/e27239/id_context.htm#CHDBEAHC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cant be done, as app store will reject apps that try to access the MAC Address